# Correct notation for the set of all non-negative numbers

Tags: notation

Which of the following notations is true to represent set of all non-negative numbers? Are they equivalent or is there a difference?

$S = \{x:0 \leq x\} $ or

$S = \{x: 0 \leq x < \infty \}$

Comment: They both mean the same in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sets are equivalent. One thing you could do is write $S=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\geq 0\}$ just so that it is known that $x$'s are real numbers (as opposed to integers say). Another notation you could use is $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ which is equivalent to the set $S$. Yet another common notation is using interval notation, so for the set $S$ this would be the interval $[0,\infty)$, which is equivalent to the aforementioned sets as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dave's answer, it is worth mentioning the notations $\mathbb R_+$ (or $\mathbb R^+$) and $\mathbb R_+^*$.

But some people use $\mathbb R_+=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x\ge 0\}$ and $\mathbb R_+^*=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x>0\}$ while others use $\mathbb R_+=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x>0\}$.

So because of this quarrel about zero (mainly between Europe and U.S), $[0,+\infty[$ and $]0,+\infty[$ are often prefered, yet you'll see the former two in many places.

I think $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ is a recent notation invented to avoid the issue, I'm not sure it is that common in older papers.